# Could anyone clear this PHP OOP concept

Tags: php

Say i have a class, this class has a method:
**a.php**

```
Class A{
  public function AB(){
    echo "Printing From AB method";
  }
}
```

Now in another file i include this class file, without creating object can i access the AB() method?
Like i can inject this class as type in another function like below:
**b.php**

```
include a.php;
Class B{
  public function CD(A $obj){
    echo $obj->AB();
  }
}
```

*If your answer is yes it will print "Printing From AB method"*
*Then could you explain why*
**Because i did not create object with new keyword**

Comment: because your $obj is instance of class A

Comment: well you'll need your `new` keyword when you provide your `A` object in `->CD()` method since it needs it. `(new B())->CD(new A());` like so

Comment: I have executed the below code and got this error:
`
$B = new B();
echo $B->CD(A $obj);
`
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$obj' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in D:\xampp1\htdocs\tester\type_hinting\b.php on line 11**
So i need to create object outside of class B then i will need to inject that Object to class B, that's the correct idea to type hinting?

Comment: Type hinting prevents passing inappropriate object type inside a function. It is a feature of weak typing languages like PHP. 
So if you want to enforce user to pass object of class A use following "public function CD(A $obj)". However, if you want to let user pass any type use "public function CD($obj)".

Answer (score 0):

Class B utilizes type hinting PHP feature since variable type is specified in method parameters declaration (A $obj).

```
$b = new B();
$b->CD(new A()); // instance of A class is passed to method. "Printing From AB method" is printed
$b->CD(new XYZ()); // throws TypeError exception in PHP7 and recoverable fatal error in PHP5
```

Let us take an example where CD method of B function is defined like:

```
public function CD($obj){
   echo $obj->AB();
}
```

In this example parameter type (A) is omitted so user can pass instance of any object.

```
$b = new B();
$b->CD(new A()); // everything is fine. "Printing From AB method" is printed
$b->CD(new XYZ()); // runtime error since script tries to invoke unknown AB() method on instance of XYZ class
```